# ¿Como referenciar la id de un body a css?

Tags: html, html5, css3

Me interesa usar el mismo CSS en varias páginas. Estoy intentando asignar un estilo CSS a un body con la `id="fondo2"`. Uso la misma sintaxis que para los elementos `input`. ¿Estoy haciendo la referencia bien?

```
<body id="fondo2">
...........
</body>
```

Y el css es:

```
body {
    background-image: url(fondo.jpg);
    /*background-color: #000;>*/
    background-size: 100vw 100vh;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    margin: 0;
    font-family: Verdana;
}

#fondo2 {
    background-color: #000;
    font-family: Verdana;
}
```

¿Puede ser porque tengo otra regla para el body en el css y crea incompatibilidad? También he probado:

```
body#fondo2 {
        background-color: #000;
        font-family: Verdana;
    }
```

Y:

```
#fondo2 {
            background-color: #000 !important;
            font-family: Verdana !important;
        }
```

De ninguna de estas formas veo el fondo negro, siempre aparece la imagen.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

En un CSS, los estilos se aplican en cascada.

La primer regla `body { /* ... */ }` se aplica al body, porque cumple con que es una etiqueta body.

Y luego, sobre esa, se aplica la segunda regla `#fondo2 { /* ... */ }`. **Está funcionando**, con cualquiera de las variaciones que probaste.

¿Por qué no ves el fondo negro? Porque el fondo negro está, pero como primero se aplica la primera regla y nada de la segunda regla cambió la imagen, la imagen queda por encima del fondo negro.

Podés solucionarlo de varias maneras:

1. Si la primera regla sólo se tiene que aplicar a algunas páginas, definí una clase en esos bodys, y modificá la regla a:

   ```
   body.tu-clase {
       background-image: url(fondo.jpg);
       /* ... */
   }
   ```

   <sup>*Sin usar esa clase donde no quieras la imagen.</sup>
2. Quitarle el fondo en la segunda regla:

   ```
   body {
       /* para todos */
       background-image: url(fondo.jpg);
   }

   body.#fondo2 {
       /* si el body tiene el id, que no use la imagen */
       background-image: none;
       background-color: #000;
   }
   ```
3. Definir una regla para todos los bodys excepto un id determinado ([no funciona en IE8-](https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-sel3)):

   ```
   body:not(#fondo2) {
       background-image: url(fondo.jpg);
       /* ... */
   }
   ```
4. Definir reglas diferentes según el documento que lo cargue (por el momento [sólo funciona bien en FireFox](https://css-tricks.com/the-at-rules-of-css/#article-header-id-5)):

   ```
   @document url(http://dominio.com/pagina-con-imagen.html) {
       body {
           background-image: url(fondo.jpg);
       }
   }
   ```

... Puede haber más que no se me ocurran ahora, pero creo que es suficiente.

Comment: Perfecto, muchas gracias!

Answer (score -1):

La referencia la estás haciendo bien, tanto `#fondo2` como `body#fondo2` son totalmente correctos, si los estilos te generan incompatibilidad de recomiendo que uses el `!important` en el estilo que requieras que sea más importante, así:

```
#fondo2 {
    background-color: #000 !important;
    font-family: Verdana !important;
}
```

Comment: Lo he probado y sigue sin funcionar